# How do I add Spock to my Springboot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spock

I'm trying to add Spock framework to my spring boot project, but I can make it work. I added those dependencies:

```
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-groovy-2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-groovy-2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.gmavenplus/gmavenplus-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

And then I created this test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = EdoobyApiApplication.class)
    class AddressServiceSpockTest extends Specification {

        def "when context is loaded then all expected beans are created"() {
             expect:
             1 + 1 == 3
        }

    }
```

This is what I have on my EdoobyApiApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { 
        EdoobyApiApplication.class,
        Jsr310JpaConverters.class 
})
public class EdoobyApiApplication {

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EdoobyApiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper(){
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:56)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptInitializerMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiDescriptionReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/igors/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.8.0/springfox-spring-web-2.8.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/ApiDescriptionReader.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/igors/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.8.0/springfox-spring-web-2.8.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/CachingOperationReader.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.CachingOperationReader]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingOperationReader' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/igors/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.8.0/springfox-spring-web-2.8.0.jar!/springfox/documentation/spring/web/scanners/CachingOperationReader.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.CachingOperationReader]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.CachingOperationReader]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:182)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;J)V
    at com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.maximumSize(CacheBuilder.java:407)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.CachingOperationReader.<init>(CachingOperationReader.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:170)
    ... 47 more
```

I'm not familiar with Spock, so I'm not sure if there is any other dependency I should add or any other configuration. Also I'm not sure I should be adding EdoobyApiApplication at the @SpringBootTest. If someone could give me a direction to look for would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` almost always means that you have conflicting versions of dependencies pulled in.

Comment: In this case, the problem appears to be Guava.

Comment: But am I importing the right dependencies then?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Spock or Spring problem.

Java will throw a *NoSuchMethodError* if the runtime method signature doesn't match the signature of the method when the class was compiled.  Another compile vs runtime mismatch is the *NoClassDefFoundError*.

In this case, it appears the version of Guava providing the `com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState` method the Springfox *springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.CachingOperationReader* class was compiled against doesn't match method signature of the method in the runtime (or possibly test) classpath.

You should run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.google.guava:guava`, as documented [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html).  Once you find which dependency(ies) are bringing in a version of Guava that conflicts with the version Springfox needs, you can add an exclusion to that other dependency(ies), or add an explicit dependency in your project with the version Springfox requires, to ensure the runtime/test classpath contains a compatible version.